# Swiftmailer and Choosing Mutiple Attachments One At A Time (Windows Explorer)

Tags: php, html, email-attachments, swiftmailer

Currently I have Swiftmailer installed into a php project And I have the ability to select multiple attachments and send am email with the attachments attached. The issue I am trying to solve is…when I click the “Upload File” section and the Windows Explorer opens, it does not allow me to select one attachment at a time, I can only use the ctrl + enter or the shift + click methods to multi-select. Is there a way to be able to click one attachment, re-click the Upload File button and click a 2nd attachment (thus not choosing them at the same time or if the files were in separate directories in my windows explorer)? How would I go about appending each file/image I select?

Thank you.

Swift Mailer Multiple Attachment

```
//Allow multiple uploads
        if($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][0] != ''){
            for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']); $i++) {
                $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i])
                    ->setFilename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]));
            }
        }
```

HTML Code For Mailer

```
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label text-white bg-secondary">You can add multiple attachments</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file text-white bg-secondary">
                            <input id="upload" name="upload[]" type="file" class="file" multiple data-show-upload="true" data-show-caption="true">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                   </div>
```